# executable java file runnable on a single machine

Tags: java, file, executable

How could I make an executable Java file which can be run only on a single machine (a copy of that file created by the person who got it can not be run).

Comment: In theory you might be able to do something with hardware, but it will be fragile and it's even more easily circumventable in Java then it is in C or C++. I don't think this question is currently on-topic here, but it might be on the [programmers stack](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If security really matters I don't think Java would be an ideal solution. As Elliott said, there are many ways to get around protection. MAC addresses are easily spoofable, there is no real HWID method for Java AFAIK, and even if there was, class files can easily be swapped out with someone else's. Some suggest obfuscating, but that just makes the code difficult to read, but not impossible. You will have to jump through hoops to make it so complex that no one will want to try and break in. It's true that the same can be applied to other apps, but it's simpler for native languages such as C(++)